# Setting multiple style items to the same value in xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-attributes

I am working on a project with multiple themes, and every theme has different values for attributes.

I want some of my attributes to be the same value, and I know I can achieve this like so.

```
<style name="theme_plain" parent="AppBaseThemeLight">
  <item name="theme_backgroundtint">#FFF1F1F1</item>
  <item name="theme_previewboxcolor">?theme_backgroundtint</item>
</style>
```

In my code I then access this value with

```
int boxcol = getIntFromAttr(R.attr.theme_previewboxcolor, themecolor);
```

When the current theme set to the app is the theme in question, this method works fine, and the value of theme_previewboxcolor = theme_backgroundtint from the same theme.

However, when the current set theme is a different theme, theme_previewboxcolor takes the value of the theme_backgroundtint for the theme which is currently set. I understand why this is, since the current value of theme_backgroundtint is set to that of the current theme.

I need a way to have theme_previewboxcolor match the value of theme_backgroundtint which was set **in the same theme**, so that even when the current set theme is different, the value of theme_previewboxcolor and the value of theme_backgroundtint as set in the theme are the same.

Thanks

Comment: is there something wrong with just using a referenced colour: @color/almost_white ?

Comment: The thing is that I have multiple different sub-themes, so in the parent I want to set theme_previewboxcolor to be theme_backgroundtint, so that they are the same even when theme_backgroundtint is then overriden in the subtheme, as you can do with attributes, so absolute color references won't work

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around, where I use enums to specify which attribute value should be read in my code as theme_previewboxcolor. However this does not allow theme_previewboxcolor to alternatively declare a new value.